# How to get array information

Tags: php

I got configuration file database.php

```
<?php defined('_ENGINE') or die('Access Denied'); return array (
  'adapter' => 'mysqli',
  'params' => 
  array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname' => 'db',
    'charset' => 'UTF8',
    'adapterNamespace' => 'Zend_Db_Adapter',
  ),
  'isDefaultTableAdapter' => true,
  'tablePrefix' => 'engine4_',
  'tableAdapterClass' => 'Engine_Db_Table',
); ?>
```

How to get only password from this array?

something like `echo $array['password'];`

Comment: `echo $array['params']['password'];`

Comment: Nope, just `$array['password']` won't work. Imagine the array is like a file system and the keys are like folders or files. You have to use the correct path to access the file you want. Every array inside an array is like a folder. So the `password` is in an array with the key `params`. The path is `['params']['password']` and that way you have to access the array: `$mypass = $array['params']['password']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I get the array from `database.php`?

You'll need to include the file and bind the returned value to a variable, such as in the below example.

```
$db_conf = require ('/path/to/database.php');
```

`$db_conf` will contain the data **return**ed by *database.php*.

**Documentation**

- [PHP: include - Manual](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

---

#### How do I read the specific value from my array?

Since you are working with a nested array the solution is not as far away as you might think. First use `$a[key]` to get to the array stored under `params`, and then get the value of `password` from there.

As in the below example.

```
$password = $array['params']['password'];
```

**Note**: *The above is, in a logical sense, equivalent to;*

```
$params   = $array['params'];
$password = $params['password'];
```

**Documentation**

- [PHP: Arrays - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

---

#### I tried the above but it's just shouting "*Access Denied*" in my face, why?

To protect *database.php* from unintended access it has been protected with a check to see so that it's being used inside of the engine.

The script will `die` if `_ENGINE` is not defined.

If you want to use *database.php* in a script outside of the thought of engine you'll need to define the **_ENGINE** constant before *include*ing the file.

```
define ('_ENGINE', 1);

...

$db_conf = include ('database.php');
```

Comment: @RadchenkoViktor turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (`error_reporting(-1);`). If you follow the information present in my post there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: When i did try to define, i got warning. Notice: Constant _ENGINE already defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/application/settings/database.php on line 1

Comment: As the notice clearly states the constant is already defined, you shouldn't define it again. What is it that "isn't showing"?

Comment: Thanks for help. I will create new setting for my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array['params']['password'];
```

Give this a try. :-)

Comment: This solution has already been provided in the other answer. Please do not post similar answers.